# Finding the value which gives a list total of zero

Tags: numerical-value

Is there a way to check if x will converge for Total[g] approaching zero in this code example?  For n=15000000, 1.87 < x < 1.88, but takes awhile to run.  Thanks.

cheers,
Jamie

```
n = 500000;
a = Select[Range[n], FactorInteger[#][[1, 1]] >= 5 && ! PrimeQ[#] &];
x = 2;
b = Differences[a];
c = Range[x, Length[a]*x, x];
d = c - a;
AppendTo[b, 0];
e = c - b;
f = Abs[d] - Abs[e];
g = Drop[f, -1];
Total[g]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about ten times faster by starting with a list that does not contain any multiples of 2 and 3, so that the smallest integer factor is guaranteed to be at least 5 by construction. Thus we only need to check for primality and can leave away the integer factorization:

```
F[n_Integer?Positive, x_?NumericQ] := Module[{a, c},
  a = Select[Union[Range[5, n, 6], Range[7, n, 6]], ! PrimeQ[#] &];
  c = x*Range[Length[a]];
  Total[Most[Abs[c - a]]] - Total[Abs[Most[c] - Differences[a]]]]
```

We gain another huge factor by noticing that the list `a` depends only on `n`, not on `x`, and can be reused between calls:

```
alist[n_Integer?Positive] := alist[n] = 
  Select[Union[Range[7, n, 6], Range[5, n, 6]], ! PrimeQ[#] &];
F[n_Integer?Positive, x_?NumericQ] := Module[{a, c},
  a = alist[n];
  c = x*Range[Length[a]];
  Total[Most[Abs[c - a]]] - Total[Abs[Most[c] - Differences[a]]]]

FindRoot[F[15000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 1.877}    *)
```

Use higher working precision in order to get a more accurate result:

```
FindRoot[F[15000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(*    {x -> 1.8770030863174339272847074995530758016555733942289}    *)
```

## update: more general case

If we want to be able to choose the smallest prime factor $p$, we modify the `alist` function:

```
Clear[alist];
alist[p_?PrimeQ, n_Integer?Positive] := alist[p, n] = Module[{L, P, A},
  (* compute the repeating pattern *)
  P = Select[Range[p - 1], PrimeQ];
  L = Times @@ P;
  A = Fold[Select[#1, Function[z, ! Divisible[z, #2]]] &, Range[0, L - 1], P];
  (* repeat this pattern up to n *)
  Select[Join @@ (A + # & /@ Range[0, Floor[n - 1, L], L]), 
    p <= # <= n && ! PrimeQ[#] &]]
```

The function now takes an extra parameter `p` that is the smallest prime factor:

```
F[p_?PrimeQ, n_Integer?Positive, x_?NumericQ] := Module[{a, c},
  a = alist[p, n];
  c = x*Range[Length[a]];
  Total[Most[Abs[c - a]]] - Total[Abs[Most[c] - Differences[a]]]]
```

test:

```
FindRoot[F[2, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 0.544595}    *)

FindRoot[F[3, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 1.1958}    *)

FindRoot[F[5, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 1.9882}    *)

FindRoot[F[7, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 2.70512}    *)

FindRoot[F[11, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 3.40701}    *)

FindRoot[F[13, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 3.96854}    *)

FindRoot[F[17, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 4.5446}    *)

FindRoot[F[19, 1000000, x] == 0, {x, 2}]
(*    {x -> 5.06328}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks I tested it to n=100000000, x=1.8251, and for n=200000000 x=1.80954.  Not sure if that will converge, but seems unlikely.  For the larger n FindRoot gave a machinePrecision digits error on 64bit OS, ignoring that I also ran into system memory error.  I would like to do the same for the list of composites with least prime factor p, ie instead of FactorInteger[#][[1, 1]] >= 5, it would be >=p for 2,3,5,7,11,.. and check the value of x in each case.  Also since the larger p lists have sparse composites, it would be good to have the same list length for all p when calculating the x values.